# Python and SQLite3 ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 10, and there are 1 supplied

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to load a csv file into my database table and keep getting this ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 10, and there are 1 supplied. I think it may have something to do with my c.execute but am unsure what the fix would be. I attached my code below for trying to insert the CSV into my single table.

My code is

```
import sqlite3
import csv

# creating my first database that will be used for the assignment.
conn = sqlite3.connect('Assignment3.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#Creating table- CCSubset with all of the required fields
c.execute("drop table if exists CCSubset")
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE CCSubset (
                CCSubset_id integer not null primary key,
                CCSubset_limit int,
                CCSubset_sex varchar(10),
                CCSubset_edu varchar(10),
                CCSubset_marr varchar(10),
                CCSubset_age int,
                CCSubset_pay int,
                CCSubset_bill int,
                CCSubset_payamt int,
                CCSubset_default int)""")
conn.commit()
f=open('CCSubset.csv')
insert sql = "insert into CCSubset values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    for row in str(csv.reader(f)):
    c.execute(insert_sql, row)
```

The error I receive is: ProgrammingERROR: Incorrect number of binding supplied. The current statement uses 10, and there are 1 supplied.

Here is the updated code:

```
# creating my first database that will be used for the assignment.
conn = sqlite3.connect('Assignment3.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#Creating table- CCSubset with all of the required fields
c.execute("drop table if exists CCSubset")
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE CCSubset (
                CCSubset_id integer not null primary key,
                CCSubset_limit int,
                CCSubset_sex varchar(10),
                CCSubset_edu varchar(10),
                CCSubset_marr varchar(10),
                CCSubset_age integer,
                CCSubset_pay int,
                CCSubset_bill int,
                CCSubset_payamt int,
                CCSubset_default int)""")
conn.commit()
f=open('CCSubset.csv') 
for row in str(reader):
    insert_sql = "insert into CCSubset values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    print(row)


conn.commit()
```

The output I receive now is:

```
<
c
s
v
.
D
i
c
t
R
e
a
d
e
r

o
b
j
e
c
t

a
t

0
x
7
f
9
b
c
8
0
7
2
4
e
0
>
​
```

So I am at a complete stand still and don't know what I need to do. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: does unpacking the tuple  `c.execute(insert_sql, *row)` do anything for you?

Comment: @AlanHoover Still get Incorrect number of bindings if I plug it into the first code and if I plug into the 2nd set of code I tried I still receive the key error.

Comment: what does that csv look like?  do a `print()` of row.

Comment: It looks like this when I do a print(row) and delete the execute and str from str(reader) but a lot more lines:
OrderedDict([('ID', '1'), ('LIMIT_BAL', '20000'), ('SEX', '2'), ('EDUCATION', '2'), ('MARRIAGE', '1'), ('AGE', '24'), ('PAY', '2'), ('BILL_AMT', '3913'), ('PAY_AMT', '0'), ('DefaultNext', '1')])
OrderedDict([('ID', '2'), ('LIMIT_BAL', '120000'), ('SEX', '2'), ('EDUCATION', '2'), ('MARRIAGE', '2'), ('AGE', '26'), ('PAY', '-1'), ('BILL_AMT', '2682'), ('PAY_AMT', '0'), ('DefaultNext', '1')])

Comment: Try that with the one that gives a list instead of a dict (the one you did not open with a `DictReader()`)

Comment: I just updated the code above so you can see the changes and the new output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see your problem.  You are converting the list that `csv.reader()` gives you to a string.  Another time you were using the `DictReader` from `csv`.  You just need the result from `csv.reader()` like this:

```
with open(CCSubset.csv) as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in filereader:
        c.execute(insert_sql, row)
```

Comment: Thanks. Seemed to have worked. Printed out a single row from the database. Is there a way I can get it to print multiple rows in the database?

Comment: Do you mean like a multi-row read?  I don't see anything like that in the docs 
 [https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll figure it out. Enjoy your day.